# Where within case en multi velues return

Tags: sql, case, where-clause, return-value, multivalue

How can i make this work

```
    where 
case [a].[ndex]
    when [b].[aantal] = 0 then 0
    when [b].[aantal] = 1 then 0 and 1 
    when [b].[aantal] = 2 then 0 and 1 and 2
end
```

Comment: What is it supposed to be doing?  What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want logic like this, assuming that `aantal` is an integer and `ndex` is never negative:

```
where [a].[ndex] <= [b].[aantal]
```

You might want to limit this to a specific range:

```
where [a].[ndex] between 0 and [b].[aantal] and
      [b].[aantal] between 0 and 2
```